# Remove item from array in Gutenberg block by index

Tags: javascript, arrays, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I have a WordPress Gutenberg block that I'm able to add items to an array in. However, I need to provide the user a way to remove a specific list item from the array of items when clicking a button next to the specific item. The data is stored as an array of objects. Outside of WordPress and Gutenberg, this will work on a basic level of removing an item by index from an array. However, the following not only doesn't remove an item, it is also blocking adding new items.

**Markup used to trigger delete function**

```
{items.map((item, index) => {
    return (
        <Button
        onClick={removeElement(index)}
        />
        <RichText.Content
            value={item['listItem']}
        />
    )
})}
```

**Used to add new empty item to list**

```
const addListItem = () => {
        setAttributes({
            items: items.concat({
                listItem: ''
            })
        });
    };
```

**How I'm currently attempting to remove the selected object from the array**

```
const removeListItem = index => {
        items.splice(index, 1);
        return items;
    };
```

I have seen suggestions of using `array.filter`, but will not remove the index from the array.

Comment: did you visit this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array

Comment: It looks like react.js tag is missing here. If so, you shouldn't mutate state directly with `.splice()`, at the very least, you should do shallow copy of `items` beforehand. Furthermore, deleting items by index may not be such a good idea, since state updates are asynchronous and by the time it comes turn to delete array item, your index may be pointing to totally different item. However, `.filter()`-based approach would be something, like `setAttributes({items: items.filter(_,i) => i != index)})`